# Clear all except the match

Tags: regex

I need clear all exepct the number above "**Height (g):**".
The number can have 1-9 digits

Exemple of text:

```
Medidas aproximadas para gravação (CxD):
1,4 cm x 3,5 cm
Tamanho total aproximado (CxD):
46,5 cm x 38 cm

Height (g):
1711

O peso e as medidas podem variar porque o mesmo modelo é produzido por diversos fabricantes
Veja mais brindes
Mochilas e Necessaires, Mochila"
```

Comment: Above or *below* ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to review the following how-to resources: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Complete Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What language are you using? Boa tarde.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the single-line `s` flag is on and then you can do something like this:

```
^.*Height \(g\):\v(\d{1,9}).*
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/AMNBaf/2)

Answer (score 0):

could you be more precise, and give us an example.
"after the clean"

```js
const regex = /\(g\):\n([1-9]*)/gm;
const str = `Medidas aproximadas para gravação (CxD):
1,4 cm x 3,5 cm
Tamanho total aproximado (CxD):
46,5 cm x 38 cm

Height (g):
1711

O peso e as medidas podem variar porque o mesmo modelo é produzido por diversos fabricantes
Veja mais brindes
Mochilas e Necessaires, Mochila"`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```